# obtainStyledAttributes in monodroid

Tags: themes, styles, gallery, xamarin.android

I'm trying to replicate monodroid example for gallery tutorial.
But the example is missing one important point : how to set the background style of ImageView.
On Android tutorial we have the following code :

```
 TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
    mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    attr.recycle();

    ....

    imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
```

I have no idea how should I replicate it in monodroid !
Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ImageView.SetImageResource(int)](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.ImageView.SetImageResource%28System.Int32%29) method to load an image from a resource Id.

Xamarin also has a [Gallery sample up on their site](http://android.xamarin.com/Tutorials/Hello_Views/Gallery) that might be more useful to you than the Java version.